# Evidences of Jewish Influence on Pre Socratic Philosophy

Tags: history-of-philosophy

**1 Kings 4:34 "From all nations people came to listen to Solomon's wisdom, sent by all the kings of the world, who had heard of his wisdom"**

**Is it plausible to speculate that the widespread dispersal of the wisdom of Solomon influenced the Sophists of greek nearly 200 years later?** Seeing how the writings of the Anaxagoras claim a divine Nous (intellect) acts as the fundamental substrate of the universe, which is very similar to Solomon's Proverb's 8:22-23 "22The LORD created me as His first course,
before His works of old.
23From everlasting I was established,
from the beginning, before the earth began."

This stipulating that the word for wisdom used in Proverbs, Chokmah, is portrayed as a thread woven through creation and governs it. Or similarly, how in Parmenides' poem a goddess teaches him on the matters of men and "true reality" similar to Solomon's extended metaphor of wisdom as a woman who will teach all those who answer her beckon as in Proverbs 8:1-6

"Does not wisdom call out? Does not understanding raise her voice?
2
On the heights along the way, where the paths meet, she takes her stand;
3
beside the gates leading into the city, at the entrances, she cries aloud:
4
"To you, O men, I call out; I raise my voice to all mankind.
5
You who are simple, gain prudence; you who are foolish, gain understanding.
6
Listen, for I have worthy things to say; I open my lips to speak what is right.

Perhaps even Anaximander's Apeiron, the infinite creative force which has no material substance because of its existence outside of time was inspired by the Mosaic Genesis and similar concepts of 'en archae en ho logos;' an omnipotent order that creates from the boundless void.

I believe it is plausible that the works of Solomon indeed traveled up the mediterranean to Greece and through Arabia, Persia, and Ethiopia and thus, over time, serve as guidelines for the establishment of sophist teachings and lifestyle of those who teach and live for wisdom.

Comment: If true this would be a Jewish influence, not Judeo-Christian.  No Christians in 500-300 BC.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit, how embarrassing of me.

Comment: Replaced "Judeo-Christian" with Mosaic as it is the most accurate term. Thanks @causative

Comment: Doubtful. This is really a question for history and archeology, not philosophy. Without direct textual evidence it would be impossible to trace such an influence. The genesis, chronology,  and mutual influences of the "wisdom literature" of the period are murky at best. While I believe most scholars accept the reality of a King Solomon, even this much is uncertain. Above all, similarity does not show causality.  But it is nonetheless an interesting field of study.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs on History SE

Comment: Unfortunately these so-called 'arguments' or rather speculations have been used for centuries now by Protestant 'historians'. Much scholarship has been done in this vein. Suggest the late University of Chicago professor Joanthan Z. Smith's book ' Drudgery Divine: On the Comparison of Early Christianties and the Religions of Late Antiquity'

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I initially had the same reaction; but I assume that if it was posted in History SE they would've migrated it here. The question is about philosophical influence; although in historical framework - but that is exactly one of the point of the "history-of-philosophy' tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question indeed.

Small remark: it's Jewish influence, not Judeo-Christian. Christ wasn't even born at that time :)

I don't think there are many historical records of academic relations between Jews and the Greeks, especially when most of the time the Jews were not treated as equals to the Greeks.

Perhaps the most obvious connection between Jewish and Greek philosophy is Philo of Alexandria [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philo)][[2](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philo/)] (his Hebrew name was Yedidya HaCohen).

Philo certainly did not influence the Pre-Socratics (he lived about 500 years after that period), but a case might be made to claim that the fact that a Jew grew up in one of the greatest cities of Ancient Greek and studied most of the Greek philosophy, surely had his fair bit of influence on contemporary Greek philosophers. Though I'll admit, I haven't found any such proved connection.

Philo lived in an era of great influence of Greek culture on the Jewish people, an era we now call the Hellenistic Era [[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism)] which began at around 400 BCE. We know that Greek philosophy and culture reached and influenced many Jewish people, to the point that the Talmud have obvious references to Greek culture (not to mention the many researches that claim that the Talmud itself is written in Greek dialectic style [[4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9004106987)]).

So, in conclusion: no, we do not have any evidence to suggest that Jewish philosophy has influenced Greek philosophy. We can see similar themes between different philosophical approaches in both cultures, but that doesn't mean direct influence as we can see them in other unrelated cultures as well. The major connection we do know of between the Jewish and the Greek cultures are in the Hellenistic Era, but the connection we have records of is one-sided. Again, we cannot disprove that there wasn't any influence the other way around at that time, but we currently don't have any proof of such influence.